# Prometheus Cloudwatch Exporter not returning correct matrix for AWS ELB

Tags: prometheus, aws-elb

I am trying to use cloudwatch exporter from prmetheus with AWS ELB.
I am not able to see any logs for ELB matrices. I can see graphs/values getting updated on the cloudwatch UI but not getting the same information in the cloudwatch-exporter

Below is my YAML file which is used as input
`
        ---
        region: us-east-2
        metrics:

```
    - aws_namespace: AWS/ELB
      aws_dimensions: ["us-east-2b", "ELB ID"]
      aws_metric_name: EstimatedALBConsumedLCUs
      aws_statistics: [Sum]

    - aws_namespace: AWS/ELB
      aws_dimensions: [us-east-2b, "ELB ID"]
      aws_metric_name: EstimatedProcessedBytes
      aws_statistics: [Sum]

   - aws_namespace: AWS/ELB
     aws_dimensions: ["us-east-2b", "ELB ID"]
     aws_metric_name: EstimatedProcessedBytes
     aws_statistics: [Sum]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

`us-east-2b` and `ELB ID` are not dimensions, you want `AvailabilityZone` and `LoadBalancerName`.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html#estimated-metrics

Comment: Even after changing the Region to Availablity zone it is not working for me .

Comment: I am getting matrices for EC2 instances but nothing for ELB